# dplyrを用いてデータフレーム内の型を統一したい

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

データクレンジングの途中で
`Error: Can not automatically convert from character to integer in column "hoge".`

というエラーが出るので、dplyrを用いてデータフレーム内の型を統一（=全てのカラムをcharacterではなくnumericに変換）したいのですが、

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34123199/using-mutate-each-from-dplyr-to-convert-all-numeric-varaibles-to-factor

を参考に

`iris %>% mutate_each(funs(as.numeric),sapply(df,is.numeric))`

を利用したいのですが、このコードの`is.numeric`を否定にして（＝数値でない時applyしたい）うまく動かしたいです。
わかる方よろしくお願い致します。

**追記**
http://qiita.com/ytakeda/items/b996d93b33803409efb3を使うこともできますが、パイプで連続処理したいです。
また、`mutate_each(funs(as.numeric), which(sapply(., is.character)))`で今回はエラー回避することが出来ました。

Comment: 何をやりたいか少し不明です。`hoge`をみせてくれませんか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mutate_if`や`muatate_at`関数を利用して、対象のデータ型あるいは変数を指定できます。

例のirisデータセットの数値が
あらかじめ数値型としてセットされているので、一旦文字列型に変更しています

```
str(iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

# 数値型の変数を全て文字列型に変換
my.iris <- iris %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, as.character)
str(my.iris)
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: chr  "5.1" "4.9" "4.7" "4.6" ...
 $ Sepal.Width : chr  "3.5" "3" "3.2" "3.1" ...
 $ Petal.Length: chr  "1.4" "1.4" "1.3" "1.5" ...
 $ Petal.Width : chr  "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" "0.2" ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

# Species列を除いた全ての変数を数値型に変換
my.iris %>% mutate_at(vars(-Species), as.numeric) %>% str()
 'data.frame':  150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Answer (score 2):

`data.table`を使うことができると思います。

```
library(data.table)
#test data
DT <- 
  data.frame(a = c("1", "2", "3"),
             b = 4:6,
             c = as.factor(7:9),
             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

setDT(DT)

char.col <- which(sapply(DT, is.character))
DT[ , (char.col) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric),
    .SDcols = (char.col)]
# DT
#    a b c
# 1: 1 4 7
# 2: 2 5 8
# 3: 3 6 9
```

Answer (score 1):

`dplyr`パッケージの`mutate_if()`には直で否定演算子を入れる事はできませんが、`function(col)`を用いることで、`FALSE`なカラムのみに関数を適応、を簡潔に実現できます。

```
test <- iris %>% mutate_if(function(col) !is.numeric(col), as.numeric)

head(test, n=2) 
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2       1
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2       1
```

`iris`の`Species`は`factor`なので数値化されますが、`character`な文字データですと当然`NA`を返します。